# Converting a MatchCollection to an array of doubles

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code that produces a MatchCollection:

```
var tmp3 = myregex.Matches(text_to_split);
```

The `Matches` in `tmp3` are strings such as `93.4` and `-276.2`.  What I really need is to convert this MatchCollection into an array of doubles.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [double.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx) method to convert a string to double:

```
var tmp3 = myregex.Matches(text_to_split);
foreach (Match match in tmp3)
{
    double value = double.Parse(match.Value);
    // TODO : do something with the matches value
}
```

and if you are a LINQ and functional programming fan like me you could save a useless loop and directly convert your `MatchCollection` to an `IEnumerable<double>`:

```
var tmp3 = myregex.Matches(text_to_split);
var values = tmp3.Cast<Match>().Select(x => double.Parse(x.Value));
```

and if you needed a static array an additional `.ToArray()` call might be necessary:

```
var tmp3 = myregex.Matches(text_to_split);
var values = tmp3.Cast<Match>().Select(x => double.Parse(x.Value)).ToArray();
```

If you want a *safe* conversion you could use the [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) method but if your regular expression is good enough and you have ensured that the string is in a proper format you should be OK.